# An unknown error occurred: user rejected certificate for github.com (-17) on Xcode 13.3

Tags: xcode, github

I'm experiencing this weird error which keeps annoying me every time I try to push my local git repository to Github. Hope someone can help me out with this weird thing. My working environment: Xcode 13.3.

[image: Error Alert]

Comment: Oh same issue for me too. I am using Github's own client now. The file status are getting updated but, no push or pull.

Comment: Does https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pkg-certificate-issue-on-linux/76623/7 help? (running `update-ca-certificates` as root)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a web debugging proxy caused this problem.

It seems that Xcode pins github certificate. So when I start a web debugging proxy as system proxy, the request fails.

Clear system proxy and restart xcode helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to first initialize git in your project folder and then only this will work.